# How do I read a CSV file using Pandas then split the columns into two Numpy arrays using to_numpy for Scikit-Learn?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, scikit-learn

In summary I want a Python 3 function to:

1. read data from a tab-separated CSV file
2. return a two-part tuple where both parts are numpy arrays (examples below):

   - the first part is all the data from all the columns **except** the first column, with **each row being its own list** (a 2-dimensional matrix)
   - the second part of the tuple is all the data from the first column **as a list** (or is it a 1-dimensional array?)
3. retain the correct types for each data item, either string or integer for now

The two Numpy arrays are to pass to Scikit-Learn, specifically [`Id3Estimator.fit`](https://svaante.github.io/decision-tree-id3/id3.html)

The problems I've having are:

1. I'm quite new to Python
2. I'm completely new to numpy, pandas and Scikit-learn
3. Many of the examples I can find are either trivially simple and don't cover my needs, or they are unfeasibly complicated for a beginner
4. Some answers I've found on StackExchange use the deprecated `.to_matrix` and `.values` methods but I want to be up-to-date

### CSV

The CSV **data are heterogeneous.** The first column is the classification, the rest are the feature data:

```
(30k,38k)   45  male    private m
(30k,38k)   50  female  private m
(30k,38k)   61  other   public  b
(13k,15k)   40  male    private none
(23k,30k)   34  other   private b
```

The second column data (which I've discovered is numbered 1 because of 0-indexing) are all integers. All other columns are entirely string.

### Data structures

The ID3Estimator comes with an example of hard-wired data and I want to adapt it to read from a tab-separated CSV file. The hard-wired data has 3 explicit data structures:

1. feature names (which I've successfully read from a separate file)
2. `instances` which looks like this:

```
np.array([[45, "male", "private", "m"],
          [50, "female", "private", "m"],
          [61, "other", "public", "b"],
          [40, "male", "private", "none"],
          [34, "other", "private", "b"]])
```

3. `classifications` which look like this:

```
np.array(["(30k,38k)",
          "(30k,38k)",
          "(30k,38k)",
          "(13k,15k)",
          "(23k,30k)"])
```

I've used `import numpy as np`

### Minimal *nearly* working example

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from id3 import Id3Estimator

def read_instances():
    """ returns (instances, classifications)
    """
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv',
                       dtype=str, # UPDATE (see below)
                       header=None,
                       sep='\t')
    # iloc[rows, column(s)] where : means "all"
    return np.array(data.iloc[:, 1:]),\
           np.array(list(data.iloc[:, 0]))
# the first part of the return seems to be incorrect

instances, classifications = read_instances()

clf = Id3Estimator()
clf.fit(instances, classifications, check_input=True)
```

### The bits that seem to work

1. All the data are read correctly
2. The `classifications` array *appears* to be in the correct format

### The bits that don't work

1. The `instances` array is wrong

Error trace:

```
    clf.fit(instances, classifications, check_input=True)
  File "\Python38\lib\site-packages\id3\id3.py", line 92,
    in fit
    X_, y_ = check_X_y(X, y)
  File "D:\_tools\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 747,
    in check_X_y
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
  File "\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 531,
    in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
  File "\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 85,
    in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'male'
```

There's also a slew of deprecation warnings related to `six.py` that I haven't included. I'm guessing it's something in the `id3` library.

I wouldn't be surprised if there's something really simple I've missed, nor would I be surprised if my whole approach is wrong. I'm not sure if using `list` to make the one-dimensional array for `classifications` is the "right" way to do it. For the `instances` part, I feel I want to do combine [`pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) with an array slice, but I'm currently too confused, and both me and my rubber duck have had enough of debugging.

The curious thing is that the hard-wired code does not require explicit specification of types. I have seen something about `dtype` or something similar somewhere but I'm currently saturated. I'm exhausted after a day of installing python and libraries (via upgrading pip), trying to figure out command line option processing (got to `argparse` *eventually* after a lengthy `getopt` wild-goose chase), trying to figure out CSV import vs Panda CSV import, and some confusion over the `iloc` parameters and array slice notation.

### Update 1

I printed out the `np.array` of the hard-wired version:

```
[['45' 'male' 'private' 'm']
 ['50' 'female' 'private' 'm']
.
.
.
['34' 'other' 'private' 'b']]
```

and the version coming from the CSV via read_instances():

```
[[45 'male' 'private' 'm']
 [50 'female' 'private' 'm']
.
.
.
 [34 'male' 'private' 'b']
```

and noticed that in the latter (non-working) version that the numbers are numbers whereas they are strings in the hard-wired version. I found that strange because they're not quoted in the hard-wired version. So I added `dtype=str` to `pd.read_csv()` which treats the numbers as strings.

So now when I print the two versions of the `np.array`, they print identically. However it still yields the same error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'male'` presumably for the same reason(s) as before the change.

### Update 2

I've got it working by adding `dtype=str` to the `np.array` call:

```py
def read_instances():
    """ returns (instances, classifications)
    """
    data = pd.read_csv(args['instances'],
                       dtype=str, # makes everything strings
                       header=None,
                       sep='\t')
    # iloc[rows, column(s)] where : means "all"
    return np.array(data.iloc[:, 1:], dtype=str),\
           np.array(list(data.iloc[:, 0]))
```

But I would still love to know whether the way I am reading the CSV file and splitting the columns is the "best" way to do it, where "best" could be "most elegant" or "most efficient." We'll have to assume that the CSV file isn't too big to fit into memory because if it were, I don't see how the could be loaded to train the machine learning algorithm.